# Best way to store a list of objects in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my current project, I am building an object list from multiple database tables. I am currently storing them in the user session (Global.asax/Session_Start) as showed below.

```
protected void Session_Start()
{      
    Session.Add("listeOF", new ListOf());    
}
```

This is working and I can use the data, but I was wondering if there's a better way to store it (by better I mean faster access). I call this data in my controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some other data store to keep it across postback requests, so if it's global to the application, you can use application cache, but if it's specific to the user, then session is fine. If there isn't that much data involved and it's not that intensive as a read, you may want to consider whether there is a benefit to caching a chunk of data vs just re-querying it when needed.

To get more advanced and present another alternative that is more involved, a [CQRS implementation is a possibility](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (also [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs)); the idea there is one data container is for transaction data, and another for reads (whether that is a separate database or table, or even a document database as some possibilities).

Comment: Then I think I should go with the application cache since there's a lot of data involved (3000 large objects) and it's the same data for each user. Thanks for your answer!